# Is there any standard extension of the Merkle-Damgård transform that handles arbitrary-length inputs?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, merkle-damgaard, compression-function

I have seen multiple sources claim that the Merkle-Damgård transform is able to build a collision-resistant Hash-function $H$ for *arbitrary-length* inputs from a compression function $h : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^\ell$ (with constant-length inputs). See, e.g., [1].

However, the construction relies on suitably padding the input $x$ to $H$ in order to:

- Ensure that the length of the string $x_{\text{pad}}$ obtained after padding $x$ is a multiple of some parameter $0 < \ell' < \ell$. This means that $x_{\text{pad}}$ can be split into blocks of $\ell'$ bits.
- Ensure that if two inputs $x,x'$ of different lengths are padded, then the last block of $x_{\text{pad}}$ differs from the last block of $x'_{\text{pad}}$.

The second property is used in the proof that $H$ is collision-resistant (if $h$ is collision resistant). However, the second property (and hence the proof) already breaks when  we consider the set of all input strings $x$ of length at most $2^\ell$. This is because the $\ell'$ bits in the last block can only encode $2^{\ell'}$ distinct  lengths.

I suspect that one can come up with more clever schemes to extend the Merkle-Damgård transform to handle any input in $\{0,1\}^*$ (perhaps use the transform recursively until a large-enough block length is available to store the length of $x$). I would like to known  whether there is any *standard* approach to achieve the same result.

[1] Jonathan Katz, Yehuda Lindell. *Introduction to Modern Cryptography (3rd edition)*.  CRC Press. ISBN 9781351133012. Section 6.2 (pp. 170-172).

Comment: "Ensure that if two distinct inputs $$, $′$ are padded, then their last blocks differ." We're talking about the input to $\text{H}$ right, the input to the collision resistant hash function itself? Are you talking about a different configuration or are you talking about the input of block of the compression function $\text{f}$? Because it makes sense for the latter, but if $x$ is the input of $\text{H}$ then no, the the difference will be in the state $s$ which is another input to $f$, unless the difference is in the last block. Or is the input $x$ by definition the last block?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I meant to talk about the lenghts of $x$ and $x'$. To clarify: the strings $x$ and $x'$ are the inputs to $H$. But the last block $B$ (resp. $B'$) of the padded version of  $x$ (resp. $x'$) will be (part of) the input to the compression function $h$ in the final step of the transform and it encodes the length $|x|$ of $x$ (resp.the length $|x'|$ of $x'$). The required property is that if $|x| \neq |x'|$ then $B \neq B'$.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: I suspect that any possible "more clever schemes to extend the Merkle-Damgård transform to handle any input length" will not be worth it in terms of efficiency gain and be devilishly difficult to analyze.  After all MD has been around for a very long time and cryptography is a fast moving field where there is a lot of incentive to find improvements and generalizations to existing primitives.

Comment: @kodlu, that may very well be the case. However, my interest is more of theoretical nature.